# Does an insurance agent have a "Duty of Care"?

Tags: insurance, tort, washington

An insurance agent recommended a property insurance policy to a client in Washington State that later turned out to be grossly inadequate (coverage limits too small), and significantly outside of industry norms.

Does an agent have a "Duty of Care" / "Duty to Advise" that would seem to be breached in this situation?
What sort of recourse could the client expect?
What kind of defense would the insurance agent likely offer?

---

I found info on [this site](http://plusweb.org/Portals/0/CHAPTER/SW0515_Presentation_Slides.pdf) that seems to indicate such a Duty likely does exist and was not met.   But it does not really address what to expect after that:  Reasonable outcomes or possible defenses, etc.